# Sagemath: Solving linear equation symbolically takes a lot of time

Tags: linear-algebra, sagemath

I have a set of polynomials $\lbrace p_{ij}|i,j\in\lbrace 1,...,n\rbrace \rbrace$ with $p_{ij}\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ as well as  degree $n$ and a given constant real vector $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$. The polynomials can be seen as a matrix $P$ and I want to solve the equation $Pz=b$ for $n=20$.

I wanted to use sagemath since inverting $20\times 20$ matrices by hand is somewhat tedious. But it turns out that the commands `solve`  and `P.solve_right(b)` take a lot of time for this kind of problem and did not terminate, finally. Inverting $P$ by `P.inverse()` did not terminate either.

Why could this happen and what could I do to speed it up? The size is not enormous even against the benchmark for runtime for matrix inversion in $n^3$.

EDIT: Additional information:

$Pz$ is simply the product of $P$ with an element $z$ which gives a constant.  $z$ is in my case the restriction of a $n$ dimensional vectorfield $Z$ and you could unterstand this analogously to characteristics for transport equations, $z$ being defined as $Z$ along the characteristic. Each component of $z$ will be a rational function in $x$.

Comment: This probably belongs on ask.sagemath.org since it seems to be a question about SageMath, not mathematics. When you post there, please provide a small example (say 3x3) of what you're trying to do.

Comment: What is the meaning of $Pz$?  Can you define that notation in the question?  Over what domain do you want $z$ to be in?  $\mathbb{R}^n$?  $\mathbb{Z}^n$?  $\mathbb{Z}[x]^n$?  Can you [edit] the question so these points are clear?

Comment: Added the information.

Comment: Please don't append "EDIT: [more information]".  Instead, revise the question to read well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.

Answer (score 3):

**Revised answer**

By playing around in [SageCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) I've discovered that SageMath can calculate the determinant of a $\ 20\times20\ $ matrix over $\ \mathbb{Z}[x]\ $ with moderately sized entries of degree $\ 20\ $ fairly quickly.  This means that you should be able to use [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) to solve your equation in SageMath.  Assuming the entries of $\ b\ $ are rational numbers, first multiply each row $\ i\ $ of the equation
$$
Pz=b\tag{1}\label{e1}
$$
by the denominator of $\ b_i\ $ to obtain an equivalent equation
$$
Rz=\beta
$$
in which all entries of the right-hand side are now integers.  Cramer's rule tells us that the solution of this equation is given by
$$
z_j=\frac{\det Q(j)}{\det R}
$$
where $\ Q(j)\ $ is the matrix obtained from $\ R\ $ by replacing its $\ j^\text{th}\ $ column with $\ \beta\ .$ Since all the entries of $\ R\ $ and $\ Q(j)\ $ are in $\ \mathbb{Z}[x]\ ,$ SageMath can compute their determinants $\ d=\det R\ $ and $\ \zeta_j=\det Q(j)\ $ reasonably quickly.  The solution to your equation is then given by
$$
z=\left(\frac{1}{d}\right)\zeta\ .
$$

The following SageMath code implements this method to solve equation (\ref{e1}) for randomly generated $\ P\ $ and $\ b\ .$ Hopefully, you will be able to adapt it to solve your problem.

```
n=20
Id=matrix(ZZ['x'],n,n)
P=matrix(ZZ['x'],n,n)
R=matrix(ZZ['x'],n,n)
ff=FractionField(ZZ['x'])
b=vector(QQ,n)
beta=vector(QQ,n)
z=vector(ff,n)
for i in range(n):
    Id[i,i]=1
    
# Generate random P and b
for i in range(n):
    p=ZZ.random_element(999)
    q=ZZ.random_element(998)+1
    b[i]=p/q
    for j in range(n):
        P[i,j]=(ZZ.random_element(21)-10)
        for k in range(n):
            P[i,j]=P[i,j]*x+(ZZ.random_element(21)-10)
    
# The following code solves the equation P*z=b for z
# First multiply each row i of the equation by the denominator of b[i]
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        R[i,j]=P[i,j]*b[i].denominator()
    beta[i]=b[i].numerator()
        
d=R.determinant()
for j in range(n):
    Q=R*Id
    for i in range(n):
        Q[i,j]=beta[i]
    z[j]=Q.determinant()/d

# Check that proper solution has been found
print(P*z-b)
```